# Usnig HTML or Dingbats as filter labels (messages)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to put a checkmark or an X instead of the default "is true/is false" text.

Using [Dingbats](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp)

```
filterable: {
    mode: "row",
    messages: {
        isTrue: "&#10003;",
        isFalse: "&#10006;"
    }
}
```

Using bootstrap and font awesome

```
filterable: {
    mode: "row",
    messages: {
        isTrue: '<i class="text-success fa fa-check"></i>',
        isFalse: '<i class="text-danger fa fa-times"></i>'
    }
}
```

But neither work :(

How do I get it to work?

Comment: dingbats works: http://dojo.telerik.com/equBU

Comment: Doh! I wrote &#10003; for a checkmark. The above was c/p from an editor that converted them.